# How to get the value of appended 2 text box using jquery

Tags: jquery

I have a appended textboxes.

```
 <td>    
        <input class = "form-control recqantity" type = "text" onkeypress="return isNumberKey(event);" name = "recqantity[]" required id = "recqantity">
    </td>
```

As a response i ll get this type of view

```
   1 text box 
    2 text box
    .
    .
    .
```

for 1 text box value i can use `var limit = $('.recqantity').val();`
How can I get the value of the second text box? Please help me. Thanks in advance.

Comment: use the class of the appended input as selector

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use index to get the value of particular object in jQuery object collection using `.eq()`

```
$('.recqantity').eq(1).val();
```

[.eq()](https://api.jquery.com/eq/)

> Description: Reduce the set of matched elements to the one at the specified index.
>
> Note that the supplied index is zero-based, and refers to the position
> of the element within the jQuery object, not within the DOM tree.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `eq` selector for targeting element by index in returned collection:

```
$('.recqantity:eq(0)').val();//1st textbox val
```

and

```
$('.recqantity:eq(1)').val(); //2nd textbox val
```